# Receiving permissions error in sql server 2005 dev edition installed on windows 7 when trying to attach a database

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-7

I am trying to attach a SQL Server 2005 database to an instance of SQL Server 2005 Developer Edition (w/ SP3) installed on Windows 7 Professional. I am getting a permissions error. 

`Msg 5120, Level 16, State 101, Line 1
Unable to open the physical file "D:\FolderName\DatabaseName.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".`

I have also tried attaching this database to a SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition instance on the same machine with the same results.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to give read access to the file, i sure that database was in another Windows, so you need to give it permissions to read and write. I have attempted un-checking the ReadOnly attribute and that works for me.